# Link to Facebook from IOS app

Tags: facebook, swift3, xcode8

I'm trying to make a link to our business facebook page from my app. So far it doesn't seem to be working. My aim was to click a button 'Facebook', have an alert pop up asking if the person wanted to open Facebook with a yes/cancel answer, and then refer them directly to our Facebook page either in the app or on the web. I've tried searching and everything I'm finding doesn't seem to help me with exactly what I needed to I tried to incorporate my own button with a link to the page I want but I don't seem to be getting anywhere. When I run my app in the simulator, the button is functional in so much as it presses and highlights but doesn't provide the alert which should then allow the person to go to the Facebook page.

Can someone help me achieve this. So far this is what I have:

```
@IBAction func displayFacebookPage(_ sender: Any) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Open in Facebok?", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {_ in

        let appURL = URL(string: "fb:/
        let webURL = URL(string: "https:/
        let application = UIApplication.shared

        if application.canOpenURL(appURL) {
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                application.open(appURL)
            } else {
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    application.open(webURL as URL)
                } else {
                }
            }

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is the issue exactly . have debugged the problem using breakpoints?

Comment: there are no errors within the code itself. but when I load this in the simulator no alert pops up asking the user if they want to open in Facebook and I don't know how to fix that. I'm completely new to this so I'm not sure if my code is right. I have actually just seen your code changes so I'll try that that and let you know. Thanks

Comment: I've tried the code and it also isn't bringing an alert and then transferring to Facebook. I didn't get any error messages though in Xcode

Comment: you are doing it wrong way kindly see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your braces are not correct. Use the following code

```
 let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Open in Facebok?", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { _ in
            let appURL = URL(string: "fb:/")
            let webURL = URL(string: "https:/")
            let application = UIApplication.shared

            if application.canOpenURL(appURL!) {
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    application.open(appURL!)
                } else {
                    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                        application.open(webURL!)
                    } else {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        let noAction = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        alert.addAction(noAction)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Great, kindly accept the answer. So it will help others too